# ShieldUI Stacked Bar Graph with Totals

Tags: shieldui

I've got a stacked bar graph that shows two categories of information.  Now I have a requirement to show the total of the bars at the end of the bar.  I've attached a mock-up showing what I'm trying to do -- the numbers in red are what I'm trying to add.

[image]
<sub>(source: [michaelandlisa.us](http://michaelandlisa.us/Images/Forums/stacked_with_totals.png))</sub>

I couldn't find anything in the documentation on how to add totals, or on how to add annotations (which would also work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by adding a Scatter chart of total values on top of the existing bar chart.

http://michaelandlisa.us/Images/Forums/stacked_with_totals_scatter.png

I also set the color on the series to "transparent" so the point wouldn't show up, and then I bumped the X and Y by 15 and 12 respectively.  I also set the style to Bold, and set the format to "{point.y:n0}".  Here's the relevant MVC code (where totals is a List of object):

```
.DataSeries(series => series.Scatter()
    .Data(totals)
    .CollectionAlias("Total")
    .Color("transparent")
    .AddToLegend(false).DataPointText(dtp =>
{
    dtp.Enabled(true);
    dtp.Format("{point.y:n0}");
    dtp.Style(s => s.FontWeight(FontWeight.Bold));
    dtp.Color("red");
    dtp.X(15);
    dtp.Y(12);
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, ShieldUI jQuery chart plugin renders the series without text, as shown [here](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/bar-chart/stacked-bar). 
To alter this behavior, you need to first enable the text. 
Then, you can use a format function to either show some cumulative text, or return an empty string. More information on this approach is available [here](http://shieldui.com/documentation/components/javascript/shieldui.chart/api/seriesSettings/bar/dataPointText/format). 
This can be coupled with a global counter to determine each Xth iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure this helps me any.  I know I can muck with the format of each data point, what I'm trying to do is add a completely separate label.  I could definitely mis-use the customPointText and do a bunch of DOM stuff to find out where the bars end and do some more math to figure out where to stick my custom labels, but what I really need is something like an annotation.  Never mind the minor annoyance of checking if this is the first or second data series so I don't end up rendering my custom labels twice.

Comment: The functionality in question, in my opinion, is not supported in the curent version of the component. 
You can use the dataPointText to only show each 3rd point (topmost) and also show a cumulative text. To fully mock the exact same layout as in the screenshot you provided earlier, you can display the datapoint text along the y axis, as shown [here](http://shieldui.com/documentation/components/javascript/shieldui.chart/api/seriesSettings/area/dataPointText/y).