# Update Series based on show / hide of other series

Tags: shieldui

I managed to get a stacked bar chart to show totals by overlaying a scatter chart on top of it here -- [ShieldUI Stacked Bar Graph with Totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192915/shieldui-stacked-bar-graph-with-totals/31208213#31208213), but now I have a new requirement.  I need to update those totals when the user hides / shows the series by clicking on them in the legend so that the hidden bars aren't added to the total.  I thought I could just hook the SeriesVisibilityChange event and run a refresh from there, but that doesn't tell me if the series was hidden or shown.  So not only can I not show / hide the bars on demand on the refresh, but I also don't know if I should be adding / subtracting the values from the totals.  Can anyone help me out with some direction on how to handle this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you cannot handle this out of the box. 
One possible alternative would be to use the format function for the text in the data point, and determine the value. More information on this option is available [here](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/components/javascript/shieldui.chart/api/seriesSettings/bar/dataPointText/format).